# How to browse files for uncompleted iOS backup

Tags: ios, backup

I have an old iOS backup but it is not a complete backup (I dismounted the phone while taking it and never made a new one.)

There are 15GB of files but since it is not a completed backup, the Backup software is not able to browse it.

How I can browse these files and get some data from it?
I used the backup tool from Finde.r[image: backup tool]

Comment: Specifically what backup software? Add them to your original question.

Comment: @SteveChambers I've edited the question

Comment: There are 3-rd party apps like iMazing and IExplorer that will let you extract from iOS backups. I don't know if they will open an incomplete backup.

Comment: I've tried them and they are not able to open an uncompleted backup. I found a workaround to open some files like images and videos in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take an unencrypted backup using Finder, it will generate a random name for your files or photos and remove the extension, in this case, you can't know the file type but you can try preview it or open it so if this file is an image and you tried to open it with preview then you can see the image

Comment: If it's an unencrypted backup, Decipher Backup Browser can help you dig out the camera roll files, contacts, and other popular/common files. Easier than the poking individual files to see what works method :) There's a free trial to be able to preview what you can see.

https://deciphertools.com/decipher-backup-browser.html

Disclaimer: This is software I work on, so I stand to benefit, financially or otherwise, from the link in my comment.